# It's it possible to customize the way json_encode, encodes my object?

Tags: php, json

I have a class which gets serialized to JSON with the json_encode built-in.  However when this object gets encoded I'd like certain attributes of it to be encoded differently.  For example, in the following code I'd like the properties to be encoded with lowercase names (i.e. Value becomes value).

```
class MyClassName
{
    public $Value;
    public $OtherValue;
}
```

Comment: The other way could be, when you receive json use function to lowercase the first letter of the object before echo-ing in

Comment: There are function such as `strtolower`, there's an option to add a method such as `toArray` to your class which returns properties the way you'd like them for encoding etc, all you need to do is put a tiny itsy bitsy of effort into preparing the data the way you need it and not expect miracles and mind reading from simple functions.

Comment: @N.B. The problem with either is that I don't want my variable names in lowercase.  So I can't simply lowercase the variables.

Comment: You're telling me that you know how you want your JSON to look like, that you are able to edit that class of yours and that you can't work out what to feed `json_encode` with to get what you want, using the code you personally own? I mean really.. this is such a simple matter, I honestly don't even know why you're asking this question.

Comment: Because modifying the class means having to update dozens and dozens of use cases.  Where as modifying the way `json_encode` encodes my object means modifying none.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about (and implement in the class) the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface.

```
class MyClassName implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $Value;
    public $OtherValue;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array(
            'value' => $this->Value,
            'otherValue' => $this->OtherValue,
        );
    }
}
```

If your class implements the interface, `json_encode()` calls the method `jsonSerialize()` when it needs to encode an instance of the class.

The method must return an array, and that array is encoded by `json_encode()` instead of the instance that generated it.

You can return whatever you want from the `jsonSerialize()` method. You can omit properties, "invent" properties that do not exist in the class, compute values, etc.

Please notice that there is no reverse method to be used by `json_decode()`. Because the class of a PHP object is not encoded in a JSON representation `json_encode()` can create only `stdClass` objects (or associative arrays). That renders such a decoding method useless.

However, on decoding it's easy to pass the array or the `stdClass` object to the constructor of the `MyClassName` class or to an initialization method that can restore the object state using the decoded data.

Comment: If I use this method, will the resulting JSON data still represent my object as an object, or does it get converted to an array?

Comment: If an array has numeric positive and consecutive keys starting with `0` then it is encoded as array in JSON. Otherwise (string keys, gaps, not starting with `0`) it is encoded as object. This is because JSON is a subset of Javascript and Javascript arrays have only numeric keys. The array keys are not encoded in JSON (that's why they must be numeric, positive, consecutive and starting with `0`). To answer to your specific question, the array returned by the sample code I posted in the answer is encoded as array in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides the [`JsonSerializable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface for this very purpose:

```
class MyClassName implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $Value;
    public $OtherValue;

    function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return array_change_key_case((array) $this, CASE_LOWER);
    }
}
```